# Jquery mobile tabs - selected tab

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a page with JQM tabs on it and below it, a "save" button.
The "save" button needs to know which one of the three tabs is active.
Is there a way for me to know it? In this example the answer should be "Two".

[Example](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tabs/)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the HTML code at least?

Comment: Sorry, I just now added the link to the example.

Comment: You added the API code, not the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: This is true. because it's that simple. Let's keep it basic and simple.

Comment: @Lighthart: At the end is the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile tabs are just the jQueryUI tabs adapted to jQM. You can use the active property to get the currently active tav:

> http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6emwLy0x/)**